# Voldemort HTTP service

Tags: http, voldemort

`Voldemort` has a `HTTP` port which presuming can be used to accept requests via `HTTP` [1]. Can anyone provide an example of how this service can be used? I've tried pointing my browser to the the port but this was unsuccessful.

`[1]: https://github.com/voldemort/voldemort/blob/master/src/java/voldemort/server/http/HttpService.java`

Answer (score 2):

The http service serves `/admin` , `/read-only/mgmt`, `/server-status` which are all viewable in your browser. It also has `/stores` but I don't know what that is used for (It expects a POST so there is no point in looking at it in your browser).

There is nothing on / so that is why you saw nothing when just going to youripaddress:port.

You can see all these listed in that java file you referenced by looking around [line 100](https://github.com/voldemort/voldemort/blob/master/src/java/voldemort/server/http/HttpService.java#L100).